# Understanding escape codes

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, escape-characters

I'm seeing this in my `.bashrc` file:

```
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\
      [\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

and I have *absolutely no idea* what all those escapes codes mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three kinds of escape codes in there: [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), [bash prompt expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Printing-a-Prompt), and [terminal escape codes](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms).

- `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` means “if `$debian_chroot` is set and non-empty, then `($debian_chroot)`, else nothing”. (See `/etc/bash.bashrc` for how `debian_chroot` is defined. As the name indicates this is a Debian thing.)
- The backslash escapes are prompt escapes. `\u` is replaced by the user name, `\h` is replace by the machine name, and so on (see the manual for a list). Parts within `\[…\]` are terminal escapes; the brackets tell bash that these parts don't take any room on the screen (this lets bash calculate the width of the prompt). `\033` is the ESC character (character number 033 octal, i.e. 27 decimal, sometimes written `\e` or `^[`); it introduces terminal escape sequences.
- `ESC [ codes m` (written `CSI Pm m` in the xterm control sequences list) changes the color or appearance of the following text. For example the code `1` switches to bold, `32` switches the foreground color to green, `0` switches to default attributes.

Comment: The ESC codes are known as ANSI Escape Sequences. You can find a lot about them on the net.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanations! :)
@Mark: That's really useful, thanks for pointing it out! I had no idea what to call them before. :)