# Italics in Emacs on a text terminal (rxvt-unicode)

Tags: emacs, fonts, rxvt

I am using Emacs running in an urxvt, and I cannot get italics to work in Emacs although the terminal supports it.

Here’s my current setup:

- I haven’t set `$TERM`, so it is the default `rxvt-unicode-256color`.
- My `~/.Xdefaults` defines `URxvt.font: xft:Inconsolata:size=15` as the terminal font.
- Running `echo "\e[3mitalics\e[m"` in the shell indeed yields *`italics`*, so italics in the terminal *do* work, basically.

When customizing the “Italic” face, it doesn’t make any difference whether I select `italic`, `oblique`, `normal`, or `roman` as the value for the `Slant` attribute, nor does it if I don’t set the `Slant` attribute at all.  I also tried this in combination with explicitly defining `URxvt.italicFont` in my `~/.Xdefaults`, but to no avail.

Bold works fine, italic doesn’t work at all.  Any ideas?

Comment: I didn't realize it was even remotely possible to have italics in a terminal.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short: you cannot with the current version of Emacs (checked with 23.2),
but see below for a possible workaround.

Longer story: support for italics is encoded in the
[terminfo](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?terminfo+5) database
as the `sitm` (enter italics) and `ritm` (exit italics) capabilities
(also called `ZH` and `ZR` for termcap compatibility); you can check
that your terminal supports them via:

```
infocmp $TERM | egrep '(sitm|ritm)'
```

If those are not present, then your `rxvt-unicode-256color` terminal
description does not provide information to the ncurses library about
the italics capabilities of the terminal and you might want to add
them, otherwise no TTY application can use italics.

However, function `turn_on_face` (in the Emacs sources, file
`src/term.c` at line 1919--2012), which manages the terminal display,
does not provide support for italics: it checks for
bold/dim/blinking/underline attributes of a face.  Actually, there is
no "italics" attribute encoded in `struct face`.

Indeed, my Emacs (version 23.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 natty) shows italicized
faces (which display correctly in X11) as *underlined* in a TTY.
(Which means that, if you do not care about underlining, you can just
change the terminfo description of your terminal to use the enter/exit
italics escape sequences instead of the enter/exit underline ones and
get italics.)

Comment: This answer looks good, but right now I can't test it because the only linux install I have is as a guest in a win7 host.  As a result I'm having difficulties testing this.  Specifically I can't seem to insert the ascii escape codes.   If someone else can test to confirm or explain what I might be doing wrong with the escape sequences I'll be happy to award the bounty.

Comment: @vschum If you're trying to change your terminfo database, [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5936/can-i-set-my-local-machines-terminal-colors-to-use-those-of-the-machine-i-ssh-in/5937#5937) should help. We can't help with your difficulties unless you explain them; you could [ask a question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about them.

Comment: @Gilles Actually, it has more to do with [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16983/could-someone-please-explain-some-of-these-escape-codes).  I can't figure out how to insert the sequences to test if the italics work or not.  When I type ESC [ 3 m nothing shows up in the terminal.

Comment: @vschum Pressing `ESC` doesn't insert an escape character. You can press `Ctrl+V ESC` to insert one, but you rarely need to. E.g. the escape character is represented by `\E` in terminfo source; in a terminal (with bash/ksh/zsh), try `echo $'\e[3mhello\e[0m'`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm adding this answer because the others are out of date.  Emacs 24.5 does correctly display italic faces in terminals.

[image]

This is emacs 24.5 running in a terminal (`emacs -nw`).  The terminal is `uxvrt` and the setup in my `.Xdefaults` is:

```
URxvt*termName: rxvt-unicode-256color
URxvt.font: xft:DejaVu Sans Mono:size=9
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding emacs not able to utilise italics in terminal emulators which provide this funtionality:  This is [emacs bug #9652](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=9652) which was fixed by Chong Yidong on Jun 10, 2012.

The fix is not in any released version of emacs though, but for instance in the emacs-snapshot package from [emacs.naquadah.org](http://emacs.naquadah.org).

Comment: This information is probably out of date....